# Substring a string from the end of the string

Tags: c#, .net

I need to remove two characters from the end of the string.

So:

```
string = "Hello Marco !"
```

must be

```
Hello Marco
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do:

```
string str = "Hello Marco !";
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2);
```

Comment: @Alexander I don't know what language you are speaking of, but in .net c#, it is a valid method. It is also the appropriate case.

Comment: I am terribly sorry - i haven't noticed c# has been mentioned. I was just looking for the method signature and found this one :)

Comment: This solves the OP's case, but it doesn't actually answer the question of how you run a substring from the end of the string. Your answer cuts off two letters from the end of the string.

Comment: @Maritim The OP's question was a bit confusing, but his explanation says and i quote "I need to remove two characters from the end of the string".

Answer (score 33):

```
s = s.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, s.Length - 2))
```

to include the case where the length is less than 2

Answer (score 21):

C# 8 introduced indices and ranges which allow you to write

```
str[^2..]
```

This is equivalent to

```
str.Substring(str.Length - 2, 2)
```

In fact, this is almost exactly what the compiler will generate, so there's no overhead.

Note that you will get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the range isn't within the string.

Comment: 9 years later, I'm one day late :)

Comment: This is the correct solution in modern C#

Comment: Even if it's what I was really looking for, the question wants the first n-2 chars, not the last 2 chars.

Comment: To get the first n - 2 chars, you can use `str[..^2]`. 2 doesn't even need to be a constant, so you can also write `str[..^"test".Length]`

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
string s = "Hello Marco !";
s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

I will trim the end for unwanted characters:

```
s = s.TrimEnd(' ', '!');
```

To ensure it works even with more spaces. Or better if you want to ensure it works always, since the input text seems to come from the user:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?'purged'(\w|\s)+\w)");
Match m = r.Match("Hello Marco   !!");
if (m.Success)
{
    string result = m.Groups["purged"].Value;
}
```

With this you are safer. A purge based on the fact the last two characters has to be removed is too weak.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the MSDN documentation (or IntelliSense)? How about the [`String.Substring` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)?

You can get the length using the [`Length` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx), subtract two from this, and return the substring from the beginning to 2 characters from the end.
For example:

```
string str = "Hello Marco !";
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's an unknown amount of strings you could trim off the last character by doing 
s = s.TrimEnd('','!').Trim();

Have you considered using a regular expression? If you only want to allow alpha numeric characters you can use regex to replace the symbols, What if instead of a ! you get a %?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var s = "Hello Marco !";

var corrected = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "Hello Marco !";
s = s.Remove(s.length - 2, 2);
```

Comment: This only gets the last two characters.

Comment: @Yuck, yeah i was going for the Remove and by habit did substring.