# Input string was not in correct form

Tags: c#

Im really bad with c# i have only really the basic knowladge of c# i have this piece of code but i cant get it to work probelly debugger says the problem is here http://puu.sh/2h2wV the code is here this is im sorry this is probally such an easy mistake
i had other code true,was my old programm :(

```
  Console.WriteLine("Sisesta esimene arv vahemikus 10-20");
            vastus1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("sisesta teine arv vahemikus 20-32");
            vastus2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Vastus {0}", vastus2 - vastus1);

            string tekst1 = Console.ReadLine();
            vastus3 = int.Parse(tekst1);   <------ debugger says problem is here
        }
        while ((vastus1 < 1 || vastus2 < 12));

        if (vastus3 >= 3 && vastus3 >= 5) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("On Kevad");

                {
                    if (vastus3 >= 6 && vastus3 >= 8) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("on suvi");
                    }
                }
                if (vastus3 >= 9 && vastus3 >= 11) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("on sügis");
               }
                if (vastus3 >= 11 && vastus3 >= 2) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("on talv");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input to the console on that line?

Comment: You should probably flip some of those comparison operators after the line you're having problem with as well.

Answer (score 4):

Well the error says it all really

```
The input string was not in the right format
```

In the context of what you're doing, this means that whatever you've typed into the console which you're passing directly to `int.Parse` cannot be parsed as an int.

If you expect that sometimes what is typed in to the console to not be numeric you could use `int.TryParse` to ascertain whether it is valid.

```
int vastus3 = 0;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out vastus3 ))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again!");
}
// here "vastus3" will have your integer
```

This can go into your code exactly where your current line which fails is.

Comment: could you mark out where i should enter it? cos i really dont get,really sorry,cos im not from uk or anything

Comment: @user2123732 - you have provided the user with a description of what they should enter for `vastus1` and `vastus2` - why isnt there one for `vastus3`?

Comment: so i add vastus3 same as vastus1 and vastus2?

Answer (score 0):

Jamiec's explanation is correct. If the integers you are looking for always occur in the same format at the end of the string you could use Substring to get the specific characters then do your comparison checks.

Here is an example on how to remove characters from the end of a string using Substring.

[Substring a string from the end of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467711/substring-a-string-from-the-end-of-the-string)

And the msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Where is tekst1 defined?

If it is a string with letters as well as numbers you still need to pull out just the integer part before you Parse it.

Not sure by the code, but do you mean to be comparing the lengths of the string?

Comment: i just some material i took it out from there. removed it got a error saying use of unassigned local variable vastus3 its in this part if (vastus3 >= 6 && vastus3 >= 8)

Comment: Put a break point at that line and step through debugger mode. Use this to find out the value that is in tekst1.